# Fild all records that have specific relation attributes

Tags: sql, postgresql, activerecord

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :contacts
end

class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
end
```

How can I using ActiveRecord get all users that eather have no contacts at all or have all contacts with 'key' attribute set to false or nil?

I was only able to do something like this:

```
user.includes(:contacts).group("users.id", "contacts.id").having("(COUNT(contacts.id) = 0) OR ((contacts.key IS NOT NULL) AND (contacts.key IS NOT true))").references(:contacts).uniq
```

But this query will also return user record if it have several contacts and just one of them have 'key' set to false...

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to find all users for which there are no contacts with key equal to true?

```
User.where.not(Contact.where("contacts.user_id = users.id and contacts.key = 't').exists)
```